# Eclipse - move statement-wise

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a way to make eclipse simulate Intellij statement-wise ctrl+shift+up ctrl+shift+down line movement? (like changing indentation, or moving code blocks)?

UPD, beg my pardon, alt up/down indeed changes indentation. But what about next:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(currentPath == null || currentPath.length() == 0) {
        showDirectoryView(settings.getRootUri());
    }       
}
```

cursor stands on method declaration, I use alt down

```
@Override
    super.onStart();
protected void onStart() {
    if(currentPath == null || currentPath.length() == 0) {
        showDirectoryView(settings.getRootUri());
    }       
}
```

Intellij just swaps this method with the next one, 
same about code blocks

Comment: I haven't use IntellJ before.  I think it will be better if you can describe what do you want to achieve actually, so more people can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALT + Up/Down Arrow` - for rows indentation in Eclipse.

*This will select more rows and move them all.*

Comment: And there is no plugin that can save me from selecting? It's not that critical, but anyway, it could be nice to have.